# Laravel Eloquent request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models: Persons and PhoneNumbers

**Persons.php**

```
class Persons extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';  
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function phoneNumbers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PhoneNumbers', 'persons_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**PhoneNumbers.php**

```
class PhoneNumbers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'phone_numbers';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function persons() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Persons', 'persons_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

My tables:

```
1) persons (id, first_name, last_name, middle_name)
2) phone_numbers (id, person_phone, persons_id)
```

I have a form for search with first_name, middle_name, last_name, person_phone.
I make a request:

```
 $first_name = $request->first_name;
 $middle_name = $request->middle_name;
 $last_name = $request->last_name;

 $persons = Persons::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $first_name . '%')
            ->where('middle_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $middle_name . '%')
            ->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $last_name . '%')
            ->whereHas('phoneNumbers', function (Builder $query) {
                $person_phone = ((new \Illuminate\Http\Request)->get('person_phone'));
                $query->where('person_phone', 'like', '%' . $person_phone . '%')->first();
            })->latest()->paginate(5);
```

And get an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'persons.id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `phone_numbers` where
>   `persons`.`id` = `phone_numbers`.`persons_id` and `person_phone` like
>   %% limit 1)

It seems that Laravel gives 'wrong' name for my columns and makes icorrect SQL. I know about naming conventions. But I can't find the error. 
Can you help me with making correct SQL with Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Persons');
```

```
$query->where('phone_numbers.person_phone', 'like', '%' . $person_phone . '%')->first();
```

Also this can be

```
->whereHas('phoneNumbers', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('person_phone', 'like', '%' . $request->person_phone . '%')->first();
            })->latest()->paginate(5);
```